# ssl.SSLSyscallError: Some I/O error occurred (_ssl.c:992)

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I encounter the error like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python\Lib\site-packages\anyio\streams\tls.py", line 133, in _call_sslobject_method
    result = func(*args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\python\Lib\ssl.py", line 979, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLSyscallError: Some I/O error occurred (_ssl.c:992)
```

When I used the proxy IP crawler, the code reported the above error.Wondering how to solve it

Comment: There is not much known here except for the error message and that you are crawling something. The reason for the error is probably because the other side closed the connection. This might be part of a defense against your crawling. There is not much you can do about it, at least based on the few things which are known about your problem.